# Given $f_X$. Integrate $\int_0^\infty \log_2 (x+1) f_X \, dx$.

Tags: calculus, integration, normal-distribution, indefinite-integrals

Say $Y=Log_2[1+x]=g(X)$ and $f_X = \frac{e^{-\frac{(\mu -\log (x))^2}{2 \sigma ^2}}}{\sqrt{2 \pi } x \sigma }$ is Log-normal density function: [[Wiki]](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Log-normal_distribution)

Find E[Y]?

Since $E[Y] = \int_0^\infty y f_Y \ dy = \int_0^\infty g(x)f_X(x)dx$. So, I do not need to find $f_Y(y)$.

$$\int_0^{\infty } \frac{\log_2 (1+x) e^{-\frac{(\mu -\log (x))^2}{2 \sigma ^2}}}{\sqrt{2 \pi } \sigma  x} \, dx$$

Unfortunately, I'm having difficulty proceeding from here.

I tried solving this with Mathematica functions but it also has no idea how to solve it. Will appreaciate any help on the evaluation steps.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replace *x* with $x+1$ in the expression of $f_{_X}$, and factor all constants outside the integral. Then use

$$\int_1^\infty\frac{\ln x}x\cdot\exp\bigg[\bigg(\frac{\mu-\ln x}a\bigg)^2~\bigg]dx~=~\frac{a^2}2\cdot\exp\bigg[-\bigg(\frac\mu a\bigg)^2~\bigg]+\dfrac{\sqrt\pi}2a\mu\cdot\bigg[1+\text{erf}\bigg(\dfrac\mu a\bigg)\bigg].$$

More to the point, $\displaystyle\int_0^\infty\frac{\ln x}x\cdot\exp\bigg[\bigg(\frac{\mu-\ln x}a\bigg)^2~\bigg]dx~=~a\mu~\sqrt\pi$ , where the quantity on $(0,1)$

is negligible. Obviously, $a=\sigma\sqrt2,~$ and $~\log_ut=\dfrac{\ln t}{\ln u}~=>~\log_2(x+1)=\dfrac{\ln(x+1)}{\ln2}$.

Comment: +1 for the clean typeset and explanation. Quick question: Did you reference an integral table for the (log,exp,power) identity you used. I've been checking through the book in the link below but couldn't find the identity. 

 http://f3.tiera.ru/2/M_Mathematics/MRef_References/Gradshteyn,%20Ryzhik.%20Tables%20of%20integrals,%20series,%20and%20products%20(7ed.,%20AP,%202007)(ISBN%200123736374)(1221s)_MRef_.pdf

Comment: No, I used *Mathematica*, which was able to recognize the *modified* expression. And thanks for the link ! :-)

Comment: Ah. more thanks to you. I got $\frac{1}{\log (4)} \left(\mu  \text{erf}\left(\frac{\mu }{a}\right)+\sqrt{\frac{2}{\pi }} \sigma  e^{-\frac{\mu ^2}{2 \sigma ^2}}+\sqrt{\frac{1}{\sigma ^2}} \mu  \sigma \right)$ on Mathematica.
Someone was asking if replacing $x$ with $x+1$ in $f_X$ would affect the "integrity" of the original problem since we're not doing same replacement on $log2(x+1)$. 
Any comment on this?

Comment: @user161581: For $\mu\ge2$ the deviation is insignificant. For $\mu$ around $1$, it is no greater than $35\%$, getting smaller as $\sigma$ increases. But for $\mu<1$, like $\mu=0$, for instance, the ratio of the two expressions can be quite large, increasing as $\sigma$ decreases towards $0$, with a magnifying factor proportional to $\dfrac1\sigma$